# Is there a single matrix norm such that for all stochastic $P$, $\| P \| = 1$?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, markov-chains

By a stochastic matrix I mean a square real non-negative matrix with rows summing to one. Denote the set of all such matrices $\mathcal{S}$.

By matrix norm I mean a norm in the vector space of matrices which additionally has the property $\forall A B. \|AB\| < \|A\| \|B\|$.

Does there exist a matrix norm such that  $\forall P \in \mathcal{S}. \| P \|  = 1$ ?

The norm has to be the same for all choices of $P$.

Is there such a norm which has a name and is easily computable?

Comment: The row sum is the operator norm induced by $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$.